# Unable to install Anaconda environment containing anaconda 4.0.0 np110py27_0

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

In Anaconda I am trying to create an environment using an environment.yml file which begins with the lines:

```
name: mytest
dependencies:
- anaconda=4.0.0=np110py27_0
```

However when trying to create the environment, I get the error:

```
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: ....
Error: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda 4.0.0 np110py27_0
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I encountered no problems when I did this seven days ago, but when I tried this yesterday I got the error.

I am running on Windows 7 64-bit as administrator, Anaconda 2.2.0 (Python 2.7 version). The "conda list" output includes conda 4.1.11 and conda-env 2.5.2.

To try to isolate the error, I installed Miniconda2 on a different 64-bit Windows 7 computer (as administrator) that had never had any Anaconda/Miniconda installed before. This is the most recent 64-bit Python 2.7 series (Miniconda2-4.1.11-Windows-x86_64.exe).

But trying to install anaconda=4.0.0=np110py27_0, either to a new environment or to the root environment, both produce the same error I received before:

```
C:\>conda install anaconda=4.0.0=np110py27_0
Fetching package metadata .........
.Solving package specifications: ....

The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda 4.0.0 np110py27_0
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.

C:\>conda create --name test400 anaconda=4.0.0=np110py27_0
Fetching package metadata .........
.Solving package specifications: ....

The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda 4.0.0 np110py27_0
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

How can I determine what is causing the conflict, and how could I resolve it, given that conda is not naming a second package in its error message? I have seen responses to other "specifications in conflict" questions in which the answer is often "Install the problematic package to a separate python environment", but in this case the new environment could not be created with the package. Starting from a clean Miniconda install did not work either. I suspect something has changed in the Anaconda repository (which would be consistent with the original environment.yml working in the past but not now), but how would I determine if this is the underlying issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue was a temporary error in the https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json file, which has since been fixed.

For reference for anyone investigating Anaconda dependency conflicts, here are the details of the investigation, and the workaround for this case:

**The cause:**

- The repodata.json file (linked above) is essentially a 'master list' of the dependencies of the various libraries in https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/. The "conda" command uses this repodata.json file.
- While the problem was occurring, the repodata.json file incorrectly listed "_nb_ext_conf" as a dependency for each version of ipywidgets. (The /info/index.json file inside "ipywidgets-4.1.1-py27_0.tar.bz2" did not list "_nb_ext_conf" as a dependency, however I think newer versions of ipywidgets require it.)
- The "_nb_ext_conf-0.2.0-py27_0.tar.bz2" and "_nb_ext_conf-0.3.0-py27_0.tar.bz2" files list "notebook >=4.2.0" as a dependency in their info/index.json files.
- The info/index.json file in anaconda-4.0.0-np110py27_0.tar.bz2 file (which is used when you specify "anaconda=4.0.0=np110py27_0" in an environment.yml) lists "ipywidgets 4.1.1 py27_0" as a dependency.
- Due to the temporary problem in repodata.json, this "ipywidgets 4.1.1 py27_0" caused conda to think "_nb_ext_conf" needed to be installed, thus causing conda to think "notebook >=4.2.0" also needed to be installed.
- But the info/index.json file in anaconda-4.0.0-np110py27_0.tar.bz2 file also specifies that the specific version "notebook 4.1.0 py27_2" must be installed.
- The conflicting requirements for "notebook" versions (4.1.0 and >=4.2.0) caused the "specifications were found to be in conflict" error.

**The workaround:**

- First, remove the line "- anaconda=4.0.0=np110py27_0" from the environment.yml file.
- Next, replace that line in environment.yml with every library listed in the "depends" section of the info/index.json file from anaconda-4.0.0-np110py27_0.tar.bz2. (Remove the quotation marks, replace the spaces with equals signs, etc. to convert the .json syntax to the environment.yml syntax.)
- Finally, remove the "- notebook=4.1.0=py27_2" line from this list.

This new environment.yml file will now list every library which would have been installed by "anaconda=4.0.0=np110py27_0", with the exception of "notebook", but "notebook" will get installed anyway due to the "notebook >=4.2.0" requirement in "_nb_ext_conf" due to "ipywidgets", and/or the "notebook" requirement in "ipywidgets" itself.

**Investigative tools:**

- The command "conda info anaconda=4.0.0=np110py27_0" gives the list of libraries required by the specified package, according to repodata.json. I put this list of libraries into a temporary_environment.yml file. Attempting to create an environment from that temporary_environment.yml file caused conda to specify that "notebook" was involved in the conflict, which gave the hint to try omitting "notebook".
- Running "conda info" lists all the libraries currently installed in the active environment. The output for the environment created by temporary_environment.yml was compared to the output from an environment from a computer where "anaconda=4.0.0=np110py27_0" had previously installed successfully. This highlighted "_nb_ext_conf" as one difference.
- I created a batch file which ran "conda info" for every library listed in anaconda=4.0.0=np110py27_0, and I looked for instances of "notebook" and "_nb_ext_conf" in the output. This pointed to "ipywidgets" as a suspect.